# Salesforce Lightning Locker Not allowing me to get Cookies

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, community, cookies

I am trying to develop the functionality of cookie settings and Accept Cookies for my Community Users.
As per the below new Salesforce functionality
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-user-consent-cookie/documentation

The Cookies are getting set as expected. The issue is when i try to check the cookies in browser and if cookies are present i disable my popup, i am not able to do this when the Lightning locker is ON. Only when i turn the lightning locker to Off it Works.

Keeping Lightning Locker to OFF i am using below code to check my browser cookies and Turn My Boolean variable to false to disable the popup and it works fine,.but i should not turn Locker to OFF right? Its a security concern?

```
  getCookie() {
        if (document.cookie.split(';').filter(function(item) {
          return item.trim().indexOf('CookieConsent=') == 0
          }).length) {
            this.showModal = false;
          }
    }
```

Please anyone help me to read Cookie when Lightning Locker is ON. Something similar to above code which works when locker is ON.

Also, is it ok to disable the locker and work. Please pour your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the cookies in the head section of the community:

HEAD

```
<script>
// Cookie Consent Section
window.addEventListener('getCookies', function (event) {
  console.log('enterEvent' + JSON.stringify(event));
  event.value = document.cookie;
  return event;
});
</script>
```

and fetch the values in the LWC

LWC

```
  renderedCallback() {
    if (this.openModalManual === false) {
      const getCookieValues = new CustomEvent("getCookies", {
        bubbles: true,
        composed: true,
        detail: { value: "" },
      });
      this.dispatchEvent(getCookieValues);
      console.log("getCookies" + JSON.stringify(getCookieValues));
      if (
        getCookieValues.value
          .split("; ")
          .find((row) => row.startsWith("CookieConsent="))
      ) {
        this.openModal = false;
      } else {
        this.openModal = true;
      }
    }
```

worked for me.

The only thing I'm struggling, is that eg `isCategoryAllowedForCurrentConsent("Statistics")` returns `true` after reloading of the LWC, it seems it does not read the values as expected. Does this work in your case?

Answer (score 0):

See Maserick's comment.

I got it to work with "event.detail.value" instead of "event.value". Then in the LWC, use getCookieValues.detail.value.